# Map leader not working for the c.vim plugin

Tags: vim

I am trying to include the c.vim plugin into my Vim.

Somehow it doesn't recognize, that I changed the mapleader to `,` and still uses `\`
I figure, that the problem is hidden somewhere in my .vimrc, so I'll attach it.

Any help will be really appreciated!

```
"####################################################
"             Basic Settings
"#################################################### 
"Set the Mapleader
let mapleader=","
"Setzt den Localleader
let localleader="-"
"Aktiviert Plugins
filetype plugin on
source ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
"Neue Dateien werden beim erstellen gespeichert
autocmd BufNewFile * :write 
"####################################################
"       Various Settings
"####################################################

" Complete options (disable preview scratch window)
"set completeopt = menu, menuone, longest
" Limit popup menu height
"set pumheight = 15
" SuperTab option for context aware completion     
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"

" Disable auto popup, use <Tab> to autocomplete
let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
" Show clang errors in the quickfix window
let g:clang_complete_copen = 1
"Automatic VIMRC update when VIMRC is written
au! BufWritePost .vimrc source % 

"####################################################
"            Basic Maps
"#####################################################

"interpreting ii as <ESC>
inoremap ii <ESC>
"cnoremap jj <c-c>
",v opens .vimrc in a new window
noremap <leader>v :e $MYVIMRC<CR><C-W>
"Y yanks to the end of the line
nnoremap Y y$
"shorcut for  copying line to clipboard
nnoremap <leader>y "*y
nnoremap <leader>p "*p
"word around the cursor is capitalized
inoremap <c-u> <ESC>BvWU<ESC>Ea 
"H moves the cursor to the begining of the line, L to the end
nnoremap H 0
nnoremap L $
"LustyJuggler is activated with ,b
nnoremap <silent> <leader>b :LustyJuggler<CR>
"mark a word in visual mode
vnoremap <leader>a <ESC>bve


"#################################################
"        C++ - Settings
"################################################# 

"#################################################
"            Various Settings
"################################################

"Spellcheking in German
set spelllang=de
set spellfile=~/.vim/spell.de.utf-8.add
nnoremap <leader>s :setlocal spell! spelllang=de

"Change the directory to the one of the current file
autocmd BufEnter * lcd %:p:h
```

Comment: Therese is no variable `localleader`. You mean `maplocalleader`, I guess. See http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/06.html for details.

Comment: "Therese is no variable", hehe.

Comment: See how smart my smart phone is?

Answer (score 2):

According to the help for [c.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/c.vim/blob/master/doc/csupport.txt)

The proper way to change the mapleader for this plugin is to set `g:C_MapLeader`

This is copied from c.vim's help. (`:h csupport-usage-vim`)

```
Changing the default map leader '\'
-----------------------------------
The map leader can be changed by the user by setting a global variable in the
file .vimrc

 let g:C_MapLeader = ','

The map leader is now a comma. The 'line end comment' command is now defined
as ',cl'. This setting will be used as a so called local leader and influences
only files with filetype 'c' and 'cpp'.
```

Also you should not need `source ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim` in your vimrc. This should be done for you.